# Is there a way to parse below Soap Request in Spring Ws

Tags: java, soap, xsd, jaxb, spring-ws

Currently the working request that is getting parsed at my Endpoint to my java Request objects is :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:gs="http://www.baeldung.com/springsoap/gen">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <gs:getCountryRequest>
           <gs:request>
               <gs:name>Spain</gs:name>
           </gs:request>
        </gs:getCountryRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But I need to send below request to Api.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:gs="http://www.baeldung.com/springsoap/gen">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <gs:getCountryRequest>
           <request>
               <name>Spain<name>
           </request>
        </gs:getCountryRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The same request is working in my case with Jax-ws and Wsdl. But I am trying to implement the same using spring-ws and requests generated using xsd.

```
Endpoint Class.
<!-- -->
@Endpoint
public class CountryEndpoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.baeldung.com/springsoap/gen";

    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CountryEndpoint(CountryRepository countryRepository) {
        this.countryRepository = countryRepository;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCountryRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetCountryResponse getCountry(@RequestPayload GetCountryRequest request) {
        GetCountryResponse response = new GetCountryResponse();
        response.setCountry(countryRepository.findCountry(request.getRequest.getName()));

        return response;
    }
}
```

The Xsd file to generate Request Objects and Response Objects is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.baeldung.com/springsoap/gen"
           targetNamespace="http://www.baeldung.com/springsoap/gen" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="getCountryRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="request"      type="tns:request"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

     <xs:element name="request">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="getCountryResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="country" type="tns:country"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="country">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="population" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="capital" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="currency" type="tns:currency"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="currency">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="GBP"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="EUR"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="PLN"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

The inner parameter  associated Java class is taking null. as value.

Comment: Is there any way to do this ?